# Extracting data from li tag under ul using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, xpath

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
   <li><a href="Resource/Guide/TCS Health Insurance - Hospitalisation Claim Reimbursement Guidelines.pdf" target="_blank">Hospitalization Guide</a></li>
   <li><a href="Resource/Guide/TCS Helath Insurance - Domiciliary Claim Reimbursement Guidelines.pdf" target="_blank">Domiciliary Guide</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get data under each li list but not able to extract value **Domiciliary Guide** from the above li list.

In the below code, list of elements is displayed as elements but first list element, `ele.getText()` is not giving any output.

Can anyone help me in extracting data from `Li`?

```
WebElement ul=testDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul")); 
List<WebElement> elements=ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            System.out.println("elements::"+elements);

            for(WebElement ele:elements){
            System.out.println("text"+ele.getText());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: <a href="#" id="dLabel2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reimbursement <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">                        <li><a href="Resource/Guide/TCS Health Insurance - Hospitalisation Claim Reimbursement Guidelines.pdf" target="_blank">Hospitalization Guide</a></li>
 <li><a href="Resource/Guide/TCS Helath Insurance - Domiciliary Claim Reimbursement Guidelines.pdf" target="_blank">Domiciliary Guide</a></li>
                                    
                                </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I hope it works

```
List<WebElement> li_value = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id='header']/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li"));
        for(int i = 0; i< li_value.size() ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(li_value.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Avnish for the suggestion but I had already tried this way and this too didn't work out.Common thing I have observed is: getText is not showing any output from the webelement in list.

Comment: @Gazal,  I have updated solution. previously we are finding element till By.xpath("//*@id='header']/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul") which is not correct, 

Try with By.xpath("//*@id='header']/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li") upto **li**. so it will work... I tried and its working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

Explanation : As the value " Domiciliary Guide " resides in tag "a" xpath should be designed till tag "a"

```
List<WebElement> tag_value = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id='header']/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li/a"));
for(int i = 0; i< tag_value.size() ; i++ )
{
    System.out.println(tag_value.get(i).getText());
}
```